# Using If - Else after resultSet

Tags: java, database, jsp, if-statement, resultset

I have created this in a .jsp file.
When I run this, I don't get my if else statements to work.
It runs without errors but the if else statements don't get implemented.
How do I retrieve the data from the db then use the retrieved data in the form of if else statements for checking. 
The database table has columns Orderid and dstatus, both string values.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <body>
       <div class="button_box2">
           <form action="trackingtest.jsp" method="POST">
              <input type="text" name="Orderid" placeholder="Enter Order ID here..." required>
              <button type="submit">Search</button>
           </form>
       </div>
    </body>

<%! public class track {

        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;

        public track() {
            try {
                connection = DBConnector.getConnection();

                ps = connection.prepareStatement("select * from Payroll.status where Orderid = ?");
                rs = ps.executeQuery();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public ResultSet gettrack(String Orderid) {
            try {
                ps.setString(1, Orderid);
                rs = ps.executeQuery();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return rs;
        }
    }
%>

<%
    String Orderid = new String();

    if (request.getParameter("Orderid") != null) {
        Orderid = request.getParameter("Orderid");
    }

    track t1 = new track();
    ResultSet rs = t1.gettrack(Orderid);
%>

    <%
        while (rs.next()) {

            String Status = rs.getString("dstatus");

            if (Status.equals("Processing")) {
                System.out.print(Status + "1");

            } else if (Status.equals("Out")) {

                System.out.print(Status + "2");

            } else if (Status.equals("Delivered")){
                System.out.print(Status + "3");

            } 
        }
    %>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you try to get next result after rs.next() returns false. As you can see in [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next()) 
"rs.getString("dstatus");" throws error because you want to get record which doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fetch a data which is not present or the data might not get loaded ensure whether the sql query is executed in the resultset